# useEffect not being executed in React

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

This seems to be a common problem but somehow I simply cannot get it to work : I am trying to read some data from a mongoDB database. If I call the NodeJS server directly in a browser, as in

http://localhost:5000/record/nilan

I get the data as a JSON string:

```
  {
   "pid":{
        "ck":"F19909120:525.522.8788.37",
        "name":"nilan",
        "cID":"0SL8CT4NP9VO"
      }
}
```

But when I am calling this from a React function `RecordDetails()`, I get nothing. Please see the code below :

```js
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router";
     
    
    export default function RecordDetails() {
     const params = useParams();
     const [record1, setRecords] = useState([]);
     window.alert('here1');
     // This method fetches the records from the database.
     useEffect(() => {
       async function get1Record() {
         //const id = params.id.toString();
         const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/record/${params.id.toString()}`);
     
         if (!response.ok) {
           const message = `An error occurred: ${response.statusText}`;
           window.alert(message);
           return;
         }
     
         const record1 = await response.json();
         const message2 = 'here'
         window.alert(message2);
         window.alert(record1.pid.name);
         window.alert(record1.pid.ck);
         setRecords(record1);
         
       }
     
       get1Record();
     
       return;
     } , [record1.length]);
     
     window.alert('here2');
     
     
     // This following section will display the table with the records of individuals.
     return (
       <div>
         <h3>Record Details</h3>
         
         {record1.pid.name}
         {record1.pid.ck}
         {record1.pid.cID}
       </div>
     );
    }
```

The process does not seem to be entering the `useEffect()` part of the code .

When this function `RecordDetails()` is called, we get the alerts in this sequence. `"here1"`, `"here2"`, `"here1"`, `"here2`"; then the functions terminates with a blank screen.

I do not get any of the alerts from inside the `useEffect`, not even the error message alert. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to change the `useEffect` condition to an empty array: `useEffect(() => { ... }, []);`

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` hook only runs after the DOM has rendered **and** when the values inside the dependency array have changed; since you don't change the values inside the dependency array anywhere except within the `useEffect` hook, it never runs because `record1.length` will never change -- the code is never reached. You may want to use the `useMemo` hook instead, which runs once and then will only change when its dependency changes. Also, in order to get it to update, you need to trigger the change from outside the hook, not within, otherwise it will not run. Thus, may I suggest something along the following:

```
const userInfo = useMemo(() => {
  const response = //make server call
  return response
}, [dependentValues]);

setRecords({record1: userInfo});

return (
  <div onChange={() => {changeDependentValues()}} />
)
```